# Google Earth API - geplugin.exe consumes all available memory

Tags: google-maps-api-3, memory-leaks, google-earth-plugin

Good afternoon to all. I searched up and down the web and did not find a solution to this rather big problem.
When I am running my app interfaced to Google Earth API, geplugin.exe comes up in the task manager and after a few user interactions with the Earth (zoom in/out, flyto a few points) all memory on their machine ends up being consumed by the geplugin. It unloads once they close my project but due to the business specs I can not keep on loading/unloading.
My guess would be that Earth caches the images and does not release them.
Anyone found a solution to this predicament?
I am running Google Earth v6.2 on Windows 7 with tons of memory.
Gratefully
Ig.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a memory leak in the google earth plugin.  It may not be the same, however, because it is not so drastic.  In my case, I was able to determine that the memory leak is related to 3-D terrain.  If I run my app with 3-D terrain enabled, there is a constant memory leak.  If I run it with 3-D terrain disabled, the memory footprint holds steady.

To disable 3-D terrain, you can use code like this.
**ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_TERRAIN, false);**

My testing was done with version 7.0.2.8415 of the plugin.